C: Are static global variables allocated even if related functions are not used?
I'm creating a string utility header for my event structs. It's meant to be only used for debugging.
The event_string_util.h header contains a single function:
const char* event_to_string(const event* e);

To avoid dynamic allocation and requiring the caller to free the string, I'm using a global static buffer in event_string_util.c. All other event string functions have static linkage in event_string_util.c.
// string buffer to return, NOT THREAD SAFE
static char s_buf[300];

And my event string utility functions write a formatted string in this buffer, and return the buffer address.
const char* keyboard_event_to_string(const keyboard_event* e) {
    const char* type_str;
    switch (e->type) {
        case EVENT_KEYBOARD_KEY_PRESSED: type_str = "EVENT_KEYBOARD_KEY_PRESSED"; break;
        case EVENT_KEYBOARD_KEY_RELEASED: type_str = "EVENT_KEYBOARD_KEY_RELEASED"; break;
        default:
            assert(0);
            type_str = "UNKNOWN KEYBOARD EVENT";
            break;
    }
    snprintf(s_buf, sizeof(s_buf), "%s: key %s", type_str, keysym_to_string(e->key_sim));
    return s_buf;
}

I read How do I prevent my 'unused' global variables being compiled out of my static library? and it mentions that the compiler is not allowed to optimize away global objects.
So, I'm wondering, even if in my code I do not have calls to event_to_string(&e), and assuming that the compiler will remove all unused event_to_string functions, will the s_buf still be allocated? I understood that I would have to compile this into a static library to remove this. What really happens, and how can I avoid allocating this buffer if event_to_string is not called?
How to prevent the buffer from being allocated?

The linker won’t link the object file if it isn’t referenced, if you put it into a library. So do that.

C the language doesn't care. The standard says nothing one way or the other. It's all about how your linker works.

@user207421 so I can only prevent this from beign allocated by creating a static library? In object files will this still be allocated?

Static space is allocated in the exe according to information in the object files. If the object file is in the exe, the space it defines is allocated. If not, not. Alternatively you could just leave the object file out of the link command.

If the function is meant only for debugging, then control its compilation as such, instead of worrying about how 'loose' code will be handled.

You could try putting the s_buf definition at function scope in the function that uses it. I don't know for sure, but if the function isn't called the linker may elide it. Put the function in a separate .o in the .a

yeah @WeatherVane, now I'm trying to figure the best way to do that. I could surround everything in a #ifndef NDEBUG, or handle it in my CMake, not adding event_string_util.c to sources

But I think the best solution is to add this header and source in CMake as a static library, and link my target against this. From the answers above, even if the library is linked against by my target, if it has no references it wont be linked.

And this is a case where adding sources in CMake with GLOB RECURSE is bad
